# jQuery select tag IE8 issue

Tags: jquery-selectors

I have two selects that initially render this way in both firefox and IE8:

```
<select id="cntctMap_PRSNL_TITL_TXT" >
<option value="Dr.">Dr.</option>
<option value="Ms.">Ms.</option>
<option value="Mrs.">Mrs.</option>
<option selected="" value="Mr.">Mr.</option>
</select>

<select id="cntctMap_CUST_SEGM_US_RETAIL_SALES_SMA"">
<option value="01">Focus</option>
<option value="02">Prospect</option>
<option value="03">Center Of Influence</option>
</select>
```

So far so good as only the first select has a value returned from the server-side, the second does not.

On document load I pull the html for the second select, i.e. `$("#cntctMap_CUST_SEGM_US_RETAIL_SALES_SMA").html());`

In IE the returned string is:

```
<option selected value="01">Focus</option><option value="02">Prospect</option><option value="03">Center Of Influence</option>
```

Notice the 'selected' attribute

But in firefox it's:

```
<option value="01">Focus</option><option value="02">Prospect</option><option value="03">Center Of Influence</option>
```

The reason this is important to me is that I want to prepend an option, i.e.

```
$("#cntctMapCUST_SEGM_US_RETAIL_SALES_SMA").prepend(selectOption);
```

And have the prepended option value show in the dropdown box, but I only want to do this for those selects that don't have a server-side value.

In IE, I can't tell which is which since 'selected' comes back in all cases. This is also true if I use `$("#cntctMap_CUST_SEGM_US_RETAIL_SALES_SMA option:selected"));` In IE, it always returns a 'selected' option.

Anyone know a way around this?

Comment: How about modifying the HTML? For example, you add a special class to `<select>` if it has a value returned from the server-side. You can then definitively target these `<select>` tags using that class, instead of parsing for the `selected` attribute.

Comment: Would no doubt work but hoping I'm missing something obvious and don't have to do something specifically for IE.

Comment: I think adding a class gives you a much more consistent result. It also works for Firefox, so it's not an IE-specific solution.

Comment: Don't believe I know exactly how the suggestion would work. Let's say there're six dropdowns on the page; some have values, some not. The server knows which is which, but how could the front-end know given the above? In other words, how would the class get assigned?

Comment: You add the classes on the server when you render the HTML. Please see my answer below...

Comment: I ended up duplicating the values driving the 'select' tags and interrogating them before determining whether to prepend the option

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in the comments, I suggest adding a special class (e.g. `has-default`) to selects that have server-side values. This is done on the server-side when you render the tags.

```
<select id="cntctMap_PRSNL_TITL_TXT" class="has-default">
<option value="Dr.">Dr.</option>
<option value="Ms.">Ms.</option>
<option value="Mrs.">Mrs.</option>
<option selected="" value="Mr.">Mr.</option>
</select>

<select id="cntctMap_CUST_SEGM_US_RETAIL_SALES_SMA">
<option value="01">Focus</option>
<option value="02">Prospect</option>
<option value="03">Center Of Influence</option>
</select>

...
```

Using jQuery, you can target selects with server-side values:

```
$('select.has-default').prepend(selectOption);
```

The above statement will only prepend `selectOption` to selects that have the `has-default` class. This is more consistent because it doesn't rely on whether browsers mingle with the `<option>` tags.

Comment: I don't believe this will work in our environment. Application server-side code (java in this case) doesn't render the tag which sits on a JSP. Apologies if I wasn't explicit enough regarding the environment

Comment: (I don't usually use Java/JSP, so I could be completely wrong.) If the server-side code can tell the JSP which selects have value, the JSP can then add the class when it renders the tag, no?